# Access: Query and Append

Tags: ms-access, append

Question:

I'm running a huge query over a query and then appending it to a table. Is it really needed to run the prior queries or i can just convert the query with parameters to an append? save me the processing time of those two queries. I guess I'm trying to remove redundancy as per query it runs for like 15 minutes. Then the append runs the same.

Thanks.

-Al

Comment: What does VBA have to do with this question?

Comment: "Query over a query" - by this do you mean a sub query? If so, then no - you don't need to run the subquery before running the whole query. They Run together.

Comment: Cindy Meister - Good catch! I've removed the VBA tag. My questions are usually vba related and became second nature. thanks!

Comment: If you do the append, then a drop or delete the next time you run the append, I think you are guaranteed file bloat in the Access DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the phrase *"running a query over a query"* means that you have a subquery within your Append query, then the answer is no: **you do not need to separately run the subqueries before running the parent query**.

Aside from the execution plan, no result data is stored by a query: the data is retrieved from the referenced tables each & every time the query is run.

Therefore, when you nest a query within another query, your parent query is not working with any saved results of prior evaluation of the nested query, but is evaluating the nested query as part of its own evaluation.